# Node's module async doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I'm trying to use node's module 'async', with its method 'each', in order to use the asynchronous version of array.forEach. The problem is that it's not working as expected, since it never executes the callback I pass it as third parameter.

Here's the code :

```
var async = require('async');

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 

async.each(arr, function(element, cb){
    console.log(element);
}, function(err){
     console.log("Done");
});
```

In fact, my program never prints "Done" even if it finishes looping through the array.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not firing the callback in the second argument.

```
var async = require('async');

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

async.each(arr, function(element, cb){
    console.log(element);
    cb(); // You were missing this
}, function(err){
     console.log("Done");
});
```

This results in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
Done
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But what's the point of that callback? Just an implementation matter?

Comment: With the async nature of javascript, you have to pass the control flow onward.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the callback function provided by async to trigger the result function, like this:

```
var async = require('async');

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; 

async.each(arr, function(element, cb){
  console.log(element);
  cb();
}, function(err){
 console.log("Done");
});
```

As described in the [async docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback).